# React Photoswipe using removed babel 5 option

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, photoswipe

I am just starting to dabble in react and one of the first components I want is something to use photoswipe.js. ([react photoswipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-photoswipe))  It looks like there is a pretty decent one on npm, but I am running into a problem.  When I run my storybook to start testing and building my component, I get an error from babel.  It says:

```
in ./~/react-photoswipe/lib/index.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\Code\GIT\DanStatenReact\DanStatenUI\node_modules\react-photoswipe\lib\index.js: Using removed Babel 5 option: C:\Code\GIT\DanStatenReact\DanStatenUI\node_modules\react-photoswipe\.babelrc.stage - Check out the corresponding stage-x presets http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets
    at Logger.error (C:\Code\GIT\DanStatenReact\DanStatenUI\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\logger.js:41:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Code\GIT\DanStatenReact\DanStatenUI\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:220:20)
    at OptionManager.init (C:\Code\GIT\DanStatenReact\DanStatenUI\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (C:\Code\GIT\DanStatenReact\DanStatenUI\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:212:65)
    at new File (C:\Code\GIT\DanStatenReact\DanStatenUI\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\Code\GIT\DanStatenReact\DanStatenUI\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (C:\Code\GIT\DanStatenReact\DanStatenUI\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:46:20)
    at C:\Code\GIT\DanStatenReact\DanStatenUI\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\fs-cache.js:79:18
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Code\GIT\DanStatenReact\DanStatenUI\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\fs-cache.js:15:14)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:365:13)
```

So I did a bit of poking around and noticed that the babel rc file appears to be set to stage:0 which from my understanding seems like a really bad idea if you are producing a component that is supposed to be durable as the javascript spec updates and evolves.

I am still pretty new to using babel though so I am kind of having a hard time tracking down what I would need to update for this component to get it working in my environment with the newer babel.  Has anyone encountered this problem with this component before?  Does anyone have any advice or tips on how to troubleshoot the bable transpile and track down what I need to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.babelrc` from `react-photoswipe` does not work with babel 6. But it doesn't need to, because [main entry point of the module is `lib/index.js`](https://github.com/minhtranite/react-photoswipe/blob/edc5b2f7473632607c25f6f89dd31007f0d12398/package.json#L5), which contains the already transpiled code. You're trying to transpile it again, and it automatically applies the `.babelrc` closest to it.

You should exclude `node_modules` in your webpack config, for example:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

It will not only fix your issue, but also reduce the build time.

Comment: Thanks.  That gives me an idea where to get started.  I am working with a project structure and configuration that is brand new to me that includes a lot of cool stuff, but also has a lot of configurations with babel web pack etc that I am just barely starting to get my familiar with.  I will see what I can do along this line.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok I am pretty sure I sorted it out.  I am building a component with react storybook and I had to track that down and put react-photoswipe in the whitelist in that tool's configuration

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael for getting me pointed in the right direction.  I am testing and building a component using a react storybook tool that has a whitelist configuration that tells it what node modules not to run through the full build.  I had to add react-photoswipe to that whitelist and it is now working... well starting to work, but this problem is taken care of.